# Getting onClickListener on RecyclerView with Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have implemented **RecyclerView** with **Firebase** RecyclerAdapter in my activity and want to get **onClickListener** implemented to it although I have tried to achieve this but something is not right in my code I guess, please help me find what is wrong.I have searched another questions but did not got the understanding and cant find the solution to my problem.

I am using Android Studio

**firebase Adapter class file:**

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null) {
            sentToStart();
        }

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postViewHolder>(

            post.class,
            R.layout.post_row_recycle_home,
            postViewHolder.class,
            mDatabaseReference
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(postViewHolder viewHolder, post model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setwebViewPost(model.getWebViewPost());
        }
    };
    mrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}


public static class postViewHolder extends RecyclerViewPager.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public postViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }

    private postViewHolder.ClickListener mClickListener;

    public interface ClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(postViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener) {
        mClickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public void setwebViewPost(String webViewPost) {
        WebView webView = (WebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.webView_news);
        webView.loadUrl(webViewPost);
    }

}

@Override
public postViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    postViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
    viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new postViewHolder().ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick (View view,int position){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
    return viewHolder;
}
```

Comment: so your `onClick` method (inside `postViewHolder` constructor) is not called or what?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1):

Move the onClickListener inside onBindViewHolder.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new postViewHolder().ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick (View view,int position){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

Remove the interface because it's redundant.Your are passing the value from viewholder to onCreateViewHolder which is unnecessary. Instead handle the click inside viewholder. Check the updated class.

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null) {
        sentToStart();
    }

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postViewHolder>(post.class, R.layout.post_row_recycle_home, postViewHolder.class, mDatabaseReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(postViewHolder viewHolder, post model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setwebViewPost(model.getWebViewPost());
        }
    };
    mrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

public static class postViewHolder extends RecyclerViewPager.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public postViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Show the webViewPost Here
            }
        });
    }

    public void setwebViewPost(String webViewPost) {
        WebView webView = (WebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.webView_news);
        webView.loadUrl(webViewPost);
    }

}

@Override
public postViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    postViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);
    return viewHolder;
  }
}
```

Comment: do not create any `postViewHolder` inside `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: No viewholder in his code is different right?I said move the code of click from onCreateViewHolder to onBindViewHolder.

Comment: no, do not add any click listeners that use `position` parameter in `onBindViewHolder` - you should do that in a `ViewHolder`, not here

Comment: I think its no clickListener but the custom Listener method which he is trying to get callback.

Comment: i have no idea what you mean

Comment: Even I am confused what that code is doing.Look carefully inside the viewholder. There is an interface and an method to register to that interface which is used for getting callback.

Comment: what to do guys, should i implement it in onBindView or not

Comment: @rohitb no, do **NOT** add any listener inside `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: I dunno what you are trying to implement @rohitb.If it is a button click Listener or something it is better to do that inside the constructor of the viewholder else you can do that in OnBindViewHolder.

Comment: @pskink can you please help me to set this onClick method with recyclerView then, i am new to android and still learning

Comment: @pskink no problem in writing in onBindViewHolder right :(

Comment: i want to click the complete item of recyclerView so that it leads me to a webView

Comment: can you post your entire adapter class?

Comment: sure in a second

Comment: @pskink i want to fetch data from firebase database, how will i do that with this on click

Comment: @Anonymous actually this is the whole class have not missed anything in the post :(

Comment: see `RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(listener);` here `listener` is where you have to add you code - now it simply calls `Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` - more here: https://gist.github.com/PierceZ/59ebfe1504c4d5ae62ed38e92f6d2fd7#file-recyclerviewfragment-java-L11

Comment: The class doesnot have the class name only..just check the post once

Comment: @pskink so i have to place my firebase get method code in place of this Toast msg?

Answer (score 0):

Please see my approach which was taken from Google samples + GoogleIO youtube sessions:

Use:

> onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)

---

```
newsAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelNews, NewsItemHolder>(
                ModelNews.class,
                R.layout.item_news,
                NewsItemHolder.class,
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference(FIREBASE_NEWS)
                        .orderByChild(FIREBASE_ORDER_BY_FIELD)
                        .limitToFirst(20)) {

            @Override
            public NewsItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, parent, false);
                final NewsItemHolder newsItemHolder = new NewsItemHolder(view);

                newsItemHolder.holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int pos = newsItemHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                        if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            ModelNews clicked = newsAdapter.getItem(pos);
                            if (clicked.getIsExternal() && !hasConnection) {
                                showSnackbar(R.string.news_with_wifi);
                                return;
                            }
                            goToDetails(clicked.getID(), clicked.getIsExternal());
                        }
                    }
                });

                return newsItemHolder;
            }

            @Override
            public void populateViewHolder(
                    final NewsItemHolder view,
                    ModelNews data,
                    final int position) {

                // Set news title
                view.titleView.setText(data.getTitle());

                // hide OR show wifi icon
                view.needWifiIcon(data.getIsExternal());

                // Set news image
                mImageLoader.loadImage(data.getThumbUrl(), view.thumbView, true);

                // Set news description
                view.descView.setText(data.getContent());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {
                if (newsProgessBar.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                    newsProgessBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                }
            }
        };
```